# How to request a file and get it or get a message in case it cannot be created from the server

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, post

Using JQuery and Spring's @ModelAndView annotation for the controller.

I'm trying to code a process in which the user clicks an icon and if a certain criteria on the DB is met, a zip file will be produced on the server containing a bunch of files, then this zip file should be sent to the browser for saving.

If the criteria isn't met, then an error message should be sent to the browser telling there isn't any file to be created and produced.

However if I use JQuery' .post method, I can receive the error message (if that is the case) but never the zip binary file.

If I use a regular Href Link I can receive the file (if that is the case) but don't know how to receive the message when the file cannot be produced.

Is there an alternative or a standard way to do this?

Thanks for your support!
-Gabriel.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably split your server-side method in two:

1. the first one validates the criteria. If unsuccessful, it notifies of an exception, otherwise it returns a URL to the method in next point
2. the second one actually returns the zip file

In your frontend, the code will look something like this:

```
$.post(urlToPoint1, data, function(response) {
    if (response.success) {
        // download the file using the url provided
        // (pointing to method described in point 2)
        window.location.href = response.url;
    }
    else {
        alert('whatever');
    }

});
```